# How to unset a variable which is previously set somewhere in Mac OS I don't know?

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I have a variable set exactly like this:

`export VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE`

I thought it would be in `~/.zshrc` or `bash_profile` but it is seen in none of those. I am now struggling to understand where its getting set and I want to reset it up. Can someone suggest easy way to do so? I am on MacOS

I am using `zsh` shell. I know the command called `unset VARIABLE_NAME`. However I am looking into finding root cause and removing the variable from the first place where its been set.

Variable name is `JWT_SECRET`

**Update:**

I tried running `grep JWT_SECRET {~/.z,/etc/z}{shenv,profile,shrc,login}` as [proposed by @nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460904)

I have configured my zsh to use ohmyzsh.

Here's how output looks like:

[image]

When I do: `echo $SHELL $ZSH_VERSION $BASH_VERSION`
I get: `/bin/zsh 5.9`

Here's what I have in my ~/.zshrc:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
PS1="%1d %& # "
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export SU_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
export SU_USERNAME=<USERNAME>
export PATH="/Users/<username>/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: No problem with that output. You do have `~/.zshrc` obviously, so as a next step, look into that one to see where it calls additional commands which could set env variables.

Comment: I have added more details about my zsh shell content. Can you please check that once and see if you find something?

Comment: As I said: You need to look into the commands run from there. `. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ` seems to be a good candidate for this.

Comment: It seems like it was cached somewhere. I tried `source` multiple times but it appeared everytime. I restarted my system and now variable seems to have disappeared. Thanks a lot @nohillside for helping me out here!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variable can be set in any of the files `zsh` reads at startup, or in any command called from one of these files. According to the man page, these are (with `ZDOTDIR` defaulting to `HOME`)

```
$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
/etc/zshenv
/etc/zprofile
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zlogin
```

So as a first attempt, run

```
grep JWT_SECRET {~/.z,/etc/z}{shenv,profile,shrc,login}
```

Ignore any "file not found" errors, and check whether it returns a match. If it doesn't, you need to manually look at each of these files (if they exist) and check for any commands which could actually set the variable.

Comment: All of those returned no such file or directory. Hmm

Comment: All? Or just some, which should have the name mentioned in the message? What does `echo $SHELL $ZSH_VERSION $BASH_VERSION` say?

Comment: Yep al, I have updated the question with the same too